# Mac screenshot of a specific window without using the mouse/click

Tags: macos, screenshot, applescript

I've been researching for a day or two but can't find a method to take a screenshot of a specific window (possibly the only window) open at a specific time using an Apple script.

Currently I have the script execute:

```
screencapture -T1 ~/Desktop/screenshot.png
```

But what I want is really:

```
screencapture -wx -T1 ~/Desktop/screenshot.png
```

But when I use `-wx`, it waits for a mouse click on the window.

Are there any utilities, built in or not, that will allow me to do this?

**Edit:** The windows alternative that I'm looking for on a Mac is the keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrntScrn</kbd>

Comment: Are you looking for a keyboard shortcut or a command you can use in a script?

Comment: Can I ask why do you need to applescript it?

Answer (score 1):

Very easy to do. Hit `Command + Shift + 3`. You will notice the screenshot image appearing on your desktop. Note you didn't have to click anything!

Now open it up in **Preview** and crop to the specific window you want.

Comment: :) just a quick comment... you still have to click on it to crop in Preview, unless you can crop images in applescript to a specific window.

Answer (score 0):

Snapz Pro X is a full features screen capture program. I use it. It is awesome. But if you're looking for a less expensive way (it's $70 I think...but it's worth it!) then try "command-shift-3". This will take a picture of your entire screen.

[TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/07/07/applescript-taking-screenshots/) has an article using Applescript to do this. You can do a `delay 5` to delay execution for five seconds in Applescript to accomplish your task.

This is a semi-dupe of this question: [SuperUser: Taking screenshots on a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/16613/how-to-take-screenshots-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: He wants to take a screenshot of a specific window without clicking on it.