# Some ways to write blog entry with screenshots in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, screenshot, blogging

I would like to ask you some efficient ways to write blog post with the screen shots from a Mac laptop.

In Windows, I would do something like: create a new page in OneNote, start to write the entry, use the clip function to take screenshot every time I need to, after finish editing, I would simply ask OneNote to connect to my blog account at: blogger.com or wordpress.com. And it will automatically upload all text along with all the screenshots as image for me, I don't need to go to a third party site to upload all the images.

How do you reach the same goal in Snow Leopard. (I did not purchase any additional package from Apple, I heard of iWork or something like that, but I want to first try with a free tool.)

Some one could give me advice ;)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not free, and I've never used it, but [MarsEdit](http://www.red-sweater.com/marsedit/) looks cool.

[image: MarsEdit]

Comment: I use MarsEdit and heartily recommend it.  Easily worth the $30.

Answer (score 2):

You can take screenshots on Mac OS X (see Question [16613](https://superuser.com/questions/16613/how-to-take-screenshots-in-mac-os-x)) and drag and drop them into a blog editor such as [MarsEdit](http://www.red-sweater.com/marsedit/) (as mentioned by fideli and my preferred blog editor), [ecto](http://illuminex.com/ecto/).