# How to take a screenshot in OS X

Tags: macos, macbook, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to take screenshots in Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/16613/how-to-take-screenshots-in-mac-os-x)

I am using a MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.5. I am new to this development environment, and previously worked on Windows.

Is there is an equivalent to the PrintScreen key to generate a static image for screen snapshot on the Mac?